# Build array of ACF marker locations (missing ] after element list)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

Error returned in console:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
```

I'm trying to get lat and long of several posts, from a Google Map field (Advanced Custom Field), to build an array with it:

```
var locations = [
  <?php
      $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'posts_per_page' => -1
      );
      $locations = new WP_Query($args);
      if($locations->have_posts()){
        while ($locations->have_posts()) : $locations->the_post();
          $loc = get_field('mapa');
          echo '['. get_the_title().', '.$loc['lat'].', '.$loc['lng'].'],';
          ?>
        <?php endwhile;
    }?>
];
```

But I can't find where is the syntax error. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I need quotes in first element of array:

```
echo '[\''. get_the_title().'\', '
```

Adding `\'`, it works.